# when I build solution or run my program my database connection automatically get closed why?

Tags: c#, database

I have make database on vs 2013 c# project.
I have add connection but when i run program connection automatically get closed. I have put con.open() in code but it gives error cannot open connection why ???

Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient) this is my database datasource.

Comment: Could you provide more information? but the reason for it. It has several possibles. normally is the connection issue, make sure the username, password, portal, and etc are correct

Answer (score 0):

Verify your username, password, connection, etc. Also ensure that your "con" object remains in scope. You didn't post code, but try to see that your code looks something like this:

```
var connecitonString = "user id=username;" +
                                       "password=password;server=serverurl;" +
                                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                       "database=database; " +
                                       "connection timeout=30";

using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connecitonString))
{
  myConnection.Open();
  //Use connection here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using and its working always.

```
Server=XXXXX;Database=XXXXX;UID=XXXXX; PWD=XXXXX;Connect Timeout=3000;
```